# Splicing a laptop power supply cord

Tags: power-supply, power, connector

I'm replacing a Dell laptop power supply with an old Mac Mini supply I have laying around. The broken Dell psu outputs 19.5V and 4.6A and the Mac psu supplies 18.5V and 4.6A. I hoping that's close enough and will suffice.

My issue is splicing the Dell cord onto the Mac cord coming out of the Mac psu. The Mac cord simply has a red wire and a black wire, as seen here:
[image]

The Dell cord has the outer layer of black rubber, then a layer of wire mesh, surrounding a layer of white rubber, then another layer of wire mesh, then another layer of white rubber, and lastly a thin wire in the middle. Here's a picture. The two wire mesh layers are twisted up.
[image]

My question is which is negative and which is positive? Here's a picture of the Dell connector:
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Solved and updated here: http://www.reddit.com/r/AskEngineers/comments/x1eye/splicing_a_laptop_power_supply_cord/

Comment: that is almost the same answer you got here except that the user did not specify which is + and which is neutral, the outside is the standard for neutral. Really want a multimeter yourself to be sure.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot mate this connector with a two wire PSU. This connector has **three** terminals: The metallic surface *outside*, the surface *inside* and the pin. The laptop uses this pin to detect the type of PSU it is connected to - otherwise it will not use external power.

You really should buy a replacement from Dell.

Comment: I just realized that the Mac cord has three terminals as well. Will that work? You can see the grey wire  perpendicular to the red wire in this photo: http://i.imgur.com/xpNpuh.jpg

Comment: The third wire is there specifically to authenticate the power supply and thus force you to buy the OEM one (standard corporate scumbaggery).

Comment: @Turbo J: I think 'otherwise it will not use external power' is incorrect. It will use external power but won't charge the battery as far as I know.

Comment: @transistor Interesting, I didn't know that. Why would they allow you to run the laptop but not charge it?

Comment: The conspiracy loonies will say it's to boost profits. As Daniel said, they're using the 1-wire protocol to pass voltage and max current capability to the laptop. If the PSU is powerful enough charging is enabled. See this [Hackaday article](http://tech-swat-team.com/howto/2287/hacking-dell-laptop-charger-identification/) which has broken links to the real article. :/

Answer (score 1):

Have a multimeter? Check which terminals are positive and ground and connect them. Dell does use a 3rd wire which operates on the 1-wire protocol to send an electronic signature to the computer which allows the battery to charge.
I'm not sure if apple chargers use the same thing or not.

https://hclxing.wordpress.com/2014/02/26/hacking-a-dell-power-adapter-final-not-really/

Answer (score 1):

Well  the white is the sense and that will make laptop know that the right charger is connected , the open sheild cable is the power, when the big thick sheild is ground ,,, but you cant use 2 wire power instead  ,,, you can use any other 3 wire board useing the same config in other power the sense can be blue like hp , or red , or grey its simple if you have a multimeter [image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is your answer, sir, as regards the d531. I really hope this helps you.

[image]